# (without Phragmén-Lindelöf) $f$ is of exponential type and bounded on the real axis, then there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(x+iy)|\leq Ce^{\tau |y|}$

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

*Question:*

Without using Phragmén-Lindelöf, show that if $f$ is of exponential type and uniformly bounded on the real axis, then there exists $C>0$ such that $|f(x+iy)|\leq Ce^{\tau |y|}.$

*Definitions:*

An entire function $f$ is of exponential type if there exist $K>0$ and $\tau>0$ such that $|f(z)|\leq Ke^{\tau z}.$

*Relevant information:*

I'm told to consider $f(z)e^{-\tau z}$ for $x\geq 0$ and $f(z)e^{\tau z}$ for $x\leq 0$ and use the maximum principle on appropriate rectangles.

*Attempt*

I am unsure of how to start this problem.

Comment: How does "uniformly bounded on the real axis" differ from "bounded on the real axis" ?

Comment: I think here there is a constant $M$ so that $f(x)<M$ rather than a function $g$ so that $f(x)<g(x)$